# CakePHP form select value as table.id, select option text as table.textfield

Tags: php, cakephp, select

I'm new to Cake. I've gotten some things set up, relevantly a "users" and a "profiles" table, controller, model and view. In my `profiles/add` view, I'm attempting to output a `select` input with the value being the `user.id` and the option text being the `user.username`. Ultimately, the value `user.id` will be saved in `profile.user_id`.

I have read through a lot of documentation, and successfully set up the `select` to output the options from the `user` tables, but it uses the `user.id` as both the value and the option text.

Controller:

```
    $this->set('users', $this->Profile->User->find('list'));
```

View:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```

It seems like this sort of thing would be routine, so feel free to answer with just a link to the documentation if I've overlooked it completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> successfully set up the select to output the options from the user tables, but it uses the user.id as both the value and the option text.

`find('list')` will by default use the primary key as the key, and the model's `displayField` as the value.

If a model does not have an explicit `displayField` but has a field named `title` or `name` Cake will automatically pick this field, otherwise it will not guess and simply use the primary-key field - which is what's happening in the question.

You can however simply specify which fields you want in the results of your `find('list')` call. Therefore either:

### Set the model displayField

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'username';

}
```

and then use:

```
$users = $this->User->find('list');
```

### Explicitly choose the fields

```
$users = $this->User->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('id', 'username')
));
```

In both cases - the result will be e.g.:

```
array(
    1 => 'firstuser',
    ...
    76 => 'AD7six'
)
```

Comment: Gotta give you this one for clarity, and all around workingness. (this is the 3rd answer I've taken for this one, the first was removed).

Comment: tip: only accept an answer when you have tested that it actually solves the question =)

Comment: Both other answers technically worked (gave a select with properly formatted value->text) but unknowingly broke other things in the process. I'd give you $$ just to sit on IM with me at this point lol

Comment: Removed my answer as well. Tip to self: don't write too many late-night answers and do it from behind my computer not on the iPad :) thanks, @ad7six

Comment: @AD7six so true. Just can't forgive myself for messing up this basic problem :D

Comment: You are god of cakephp @AD7six  :)