# CakePHP foreignKey not being saved in belongsTo relation

Tags: php, cakephp, save, belongs-to

I have a table `profiles` and a table `users`, and `profiles` has a `belongsTo` relationship with `users`. On my `profiles/edit` view, I have a dropdown of existing `users` to select from.

However, the `users.id` is not being saved in `profiles.user_id`, as I would expect.

ProfilesController.php -> edit:

```
$this->set('users', $this->Profile->User->find('list'));
```

And in View -> Profiles -> edit.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->input('User');
```

Running `debug($this->request);` in the controller shows that the proper values are being sent back to the controller. The save action looks like:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if ($this->Profile->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile has been saved'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

In the returned data:

```
data => array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'User' => '3',
                    ...
```

Comment: Don't see a problem in this part of your code. Have you checked the SQL statements if debug is enabled?

Comment: @thaJeztah the query report in debug does not show the user_id being saved.

Comment: But it is present in the request-data as Profile => user_id? Weird.

Comment: @thaJeztah is returned as "User", see edit

Comment: I'm starting to think I've given you the wrong advice in my previous answer :blush: was using the convention for HABTM inputs. See @ad7six answer, but you'll have to change the name of your viewVar in order to have the dropdown being properly propagated with the user-ids.

Comment: I think the correct name for the viewVar should be 'user_ids' to have CakePHP automatically use it, thus `$this->set('user_ids', $this->Profile->User->find('list'));`, but I'm not behind my computer at the moment.

Comment: no, `$users` will automatically be picked up for a field named `user_ids` =). Know also that you can simply pass the options into the input call

Comment: Hm, that would not explain why the original situation of the OP didn't work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464393/cakephp-form-select-value-as-table-id-select-option-text-as-table-textfield). Pretty hard for me to check ATM as I'm on my iPad currently

Comment: @AD7six the first question was about the drop down not populating, this question was about it not saving. While the previous question's answer was partially correct, it partially broke it too, setting up this question.

Comment: someone is confused =) this question has the field name wrong such that saving will not work. The other question says, it works but `uses the user.id as both the value and the option text` - that's not the same problem as the select having no values to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is wrong:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User');
```

You *don't* have a field named "User" in your `Profile` model. This should be:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```