# How to change cakephp default value in select List?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I need to change cakephp default value from select box.Here in controller I have coded

```
$madDivisions = $this->MadStore->MadDivisions->find('list');
```

In view

```
<?php
      echo $this->Form->input('mad_divisions_id',array( 'label' => false, 'class'=>'form-control','id'=>'select' ));
?>
```

After add jquery val() method

```
<script>
    $('#select').change(function(){
        var a=$('#select').val();
        alert(a);
    })
</script>
```

It showing me 1,2......

But I want to change this default value and want to replace divisions name as a value.Like as

```
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="Dhaka">Dhaka</option>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15467093/1392379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for find method with **list**

```
    $madDivisions = $this->MadStore->MadDivisions->find(    'list', 
                                                            array(
                                                                    'fields' => array(
                                                                                    'city_name', 
                                                                                    'city_name'
                                                                                )
                                                            )
                                                        );
```

**city_name** is the column name from database table which contains values for London, Dhaka.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->MadStore->MadDivisions->find('list');` will return a list of results based on the `$displayField` you have set in the model. You possibly have the `$displayField` set as the id of the table or it may not be set at all. Change this to whatever field that you want returned in a list. [cakephp find list](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) more info